# Product Catalog edit in magento 2.1.1 will result to 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm having a problem in my magento 2.1.1 site. Whenever I edit a product under catalog in admin. It will result to 500 Internal Server Error.

Also this is the error message in the logs.

```
Sat Nov 12 16:38:45.454203 2016] [core:error] [pid 25279] [client 123.252.223.212:21815] End of script output before headers: index.php, referer: http://site.sample/admin123/catalog/product/index/key/b61e460d10cf72cbccbd1719d2a08de7cd5668551fc480ff4944fcc87bfcae3f/
```

[image]

Here is the error also in console

[image]

Comment: please check your log and also check that you are not missing any html tag.

Comment: Hello Ronak, Ok I''l Check again and paste it here.

Comment: HTML tag is not missing, What could be the possible cause of this do you have idea?

Comment: have you checked error log?

Comment: Yes I checked the logs